# interactive plot python for DBSCAN clustering

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to build a code for interactive DBSCAN clustering method. But when I run it I get some errors. But when I'm getting an error says "NameError: name 'train_test_split' is not defined
even I tried to import it using : from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

How can I solve to have the interactive plot working proberly?

```
df_mv = pd.read_csv(r"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HanaBachi/MachineLearning/main/multishape.csv")
text_trap = io.StringIO()
sys.stdout = text_trap

l = widgets.Text(value='     DBSCAN, Hana Bachi, The University of Texas at Austin',
                 layout=Layout(width='950px', height='30px'))

eps = widgets.FloatSlider(min=0, max = 2, value=0.1, step = 0.1, description = 'eps',orientation='horizontal', style = {'description_width': 'initial'}, continuous_update=False)
minPts = widgets.FloatSlider(min=0, max = 5, value=1, step = 1, description = 'minPts %',orientation='horizontal',style = {'description_width': 'initial'}, continuous_update=False)

color = ['blue','red','green','yellow','orange','white','magenta','cyan']
style = {'description_width': 'initial'}

ui = widgets.HBox([eps,minPts],)
ui2 = widgets.VBox([l,ui],)

# create activation function plots

def DBSCAN_plot(eps, minPts):
    db = DBSCAN(eps=0.155, min_samples=5).fit(df_mv)
    labels =  db.labels_
    n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
    x = df_mv.values[:,0]
    y = df_mv.values[:,1]
    cmap = plt.cm.rainbow
    #norm = mc.BoundaryNorm(labels, cmap.N)

    plt.figure(figsize=(14,7))
    plt.scatter(x, y, c=labels, cmap='tab10', s=50)
    plt.scatter(x[np.where(labels==-1)], y[np.where(labels==-1)], c='k', marker='x', s=100)
    plt.title('DBSCAN of non-spherical data with noise', fontsize = 20)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()
                 
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.0, bottom=0.0, right=2.0, top=1.0, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.3)
    plt.show()
    
interactive_plot1 = widgets.interactive_output(DBSCAN_plot, {'eps': eps})
interactive_plot1 = widgets.interactive_output(DBSCAN_plot, {'minPts': minPts})
interactive_plot1.clear_output(wait = True)                                                       # reduce flickering by delaying plot updating

# create dashboard/formatting

uia = widgets.HBox([interactive_plot1],)
uia2 = widgets.VBox([eps, uia],)

uib = widgets.HBox([interactive_plot1],)
uib2 = widgets.VBox([minPts, uib],)

display(uib2, interactive_plot)                           # display the interactive plot
```

I'm trying to build an interactive plot for DBSCAN clustering

Comment: Is this the complete code? How is `df_mv` being defined in `DBSCAN_plot`?

Comment: this is df_mv. It's the data set                                                                                  
 df_mv = pd.read_csv(r"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HanaBachi/MachineLearning/main/multishape.csv")

Comment: So df_mv is a pandas dataframe. I assume you are converting the dataframe to an array and then splitting it using train_test_split? Can you post the part of the code that does this?

Comment: this is the entire code.

Comment: Are your sure you have sklearn installed? Try running `from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split` standalone. If it raises a ModuelNotFoundError then install sklearn using pip first.

Comment: yes, I'm sure I installed sklearn and also using this from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split